Is there a way to calculate this probability cleanly without brute force?
Let $L$ and $a$ be positive integer constants. I will flip a coin $L$ times. Let $n_1, \ldots, n_s$ be the count of consecutive runs of the same flip. For example, if $L = 5$ and I flipped $HHTHT$, then $n_1 = 2, n_2 = 1, n_3 = 1, n_4 = 1$. Note $L = \sum n_i$. Let $X$ denote the random variable representing $(n_1 + 1) (n_2 + 1) \cdots (n_s+1) - 1$. What is $Pr(X < a)$ in terms of a and L?
I would prefer something of the form $Pr(X < a) = $, but if it is a bound (please no Markov lol) that's also fine.

It is not going to be a simple distribution: with $L=4$ then $P(X=a)$ for $a=4,7,8,11,15$ seem to be $\frac18,\frac28,\frac18,\frac38,\frac18$ respectively.  The ends of the range of possible values are $L$ and $2^{L}-1$ each with probability $2^{1-L}$.

I am fine with approximations of this probability distribution. After plotting histograms of this distribution with large values of L, it seems like there is a nice skewed bell shaped curve and I was wondering what the shape of the curve is.  Reminds me of log x / x.

I'm curious: Why the interest in $\left(\prod_{i=1}^s(n_i+1)\right)-1$ instead of simply $\prod_{i=1}^sn_i$?

@r.e.s. The original problem was actually a number theory problem. I’m studying the growth rate after applying sequences of two vieta jumps (hence Heads and Tails) to a solution of quadratic diophantine equation. I found the growth of the largest solution was bounded on the order of some exponential to X. (n_i + 1) represents the fact that a jump always increases the values of the solution. After I couldn’t find number theoretic ways to tackle the problem, i turned to probability

Let $\xi$ be the number of times the sequence changes (so it's $s-1$), then $\xi\sim Bin(L-1,1/2)$ as the changes ($H\to T$ and $T\to H$) are independent and can occur between tosses $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$ etc. until $(L-1,L)$. Assuming that we do infinitely many tosses,  each run has geometric$(1/2)$ distribution, denote them $\xi_1$, $\xi_2$, ... with $\mathbb{P}(\xi=m)=2^{-k}$, $k=1,2,\dots$. Hence if $Z_s=(\xi_1+1)(\xi_2+1)\dots (\xi_s+1)$ then
$$
\frac{\log Z_s -s\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{s}}\to \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$
by the CLT
where
$$
\mu=\mathbb{E}\log (\xi+1)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log(k+1)}{2^k}=1.0156...,
$$
$$
\sigma^2=\mathbb{Var}[\log (\xi+1)]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log^2(k+1)}{2^k}-\mu^2=0.147...
$$
Now we know that $s\sim L/2$ as the mean of $Bin(L-1,1/2)$ so
$$
\mathbb{P}(X<a)\approx \mathbb{P}(\log Z_{L/2}< \log  a)
=\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\log Z_{L/2}-L\mu/2}{\sigma\sqrt{L/2}}< \frac{\log a-L\mu/2}{\sigma\sqrt{L/2}}\right)\asymp \Phi\left(\frac{\log a-L\mu/2}{\sigma\sqrt{L/2}}\right)
$$
where $\Phi$ is the CDF of normal distribution.

Hi, can you explain why we can replace $s$ with $L/2$. Is this from the central limit theorem?

Yes, as  if $X\sim Bin(n,p)$ then $X=Y_1+\dots+Y_n$ where $Y_i$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli($p$).

To my knowledge of the CLT, each of the X_i's (approximating with geometric random variable) have to be independent. In this case, we need that $\sum X_i = L$ which means they are not independent. Does this argument still hold, and are you using the fact that this is going off to infinity to justify using CLT? Also, I don't see how $Pr(X < a) = Pr(\log Z_{L/2} < \log a)$.

@vincent2: this is an approximation, of course we cannot say $s=L/2$.

thanks! is there any way to approximate the error of the approximation?

Of course, there are very good (large deviation) estimates on how far can $s$ be from $L/2$. See e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292004/large-deviations-of-binomial-distribution
